# Mockito-Mock functions within scala object for unit testing

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, partial-mocks

I have a few functions within a scala object. The functions internally call other functions of the same object.

```scala
object A {

    def method1:Unit= {
        spark=CreateSparkSession.create()
        Method2(spark,dbnm)
    }

    def Method2(spark:Sparksession, dbnm:String):Unit= {
        //some implementation 
    }
}
```

How can I write Unit testcase for Method1 without actually invoking method2.

CreateSparksession is another object with create method that returns sparksession.

Comment: I cannot refactor the code and need to write test case for the as is code.

Comment: What did you try? What's not working?

Comment: What does method2 do that you need to mock it? Most of the time there's no need to mock anything in an `object`.

Comment: method2 has its own logic to connect to DB and perform few transformations. It returns boolean or is a void function . So, when testing for method1, I wish to mock the return for methodB and not call it.

Comment: Modified the code sample to a more realistic one.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock methods in an object. And you *should not* mock methods in class that you are testing (if it looks like you need to, it is a definite symptom of violating the single responsibility principle).

What you can do is something like this:

```
    trait Api1 {
       def method1(
         ...
      ): Unit // NB: also, should not really return a Unit: how are you going to test this???
    }
    
    trait Api2 { 
       def method2(...): Unit // See above  
    }

    class Impl2 extends Api2 { 
       def method2(...) = // Do stuff 
    }

    class Impl1(val api2: Api2) extends Api1 { 
        def method1(...) = { ... ; api2.method2(); ... }
    }

    // You should not really need this, but, you can have it if you want
    object A extends Impl1(new Impl2)
```

So, now testing this code is trivial:

```
     describe("Impl2") {
       it ("does nothing") {
          new Impl2().method2("foo") 
          // Nothing happens
          // this is what I meant: how do you know it worked?
        }
     }

     describe("Impl1") { 
       it ("does nothinig") {
         val a2 = mock[Api2] 
         doNothing when a2 method2(any)
         val fixture = new Impl1(a2)
     
         fixture.method1()
         // Again, nothing happens!

         verify(a2).nothing("foo")
     }
```

Comment: I will not be able to refactoring the code and unfortunately need to test what is already coded.

Comment: Why "won't you be able to refactor"??? Try harder ...

Comment: We have it in our plan, but for now the need is to get the testcases done :(

Comment: Your plan is wrong. Making code testable is a prerequisite for adding tests. Also, not really much to "plan" here. The refactor takes like 10 minutes.

Comment: Definitely . But this is just one small part. I am afraid the actual production code is huge and will need detailed planning to implement the changes and thorough testing to make sure the code works end to end  as expected. Hence, looking out for ways to write the testcase for this one as is.

Comment: We are not talking about "huge code" and "detailed planning". To implement _one_ test case you are asking about here, there is _ten minutes_ overhead to split it into classes. If you are saying ten minutes is too much, and asking how to mock object methods, the answer is you can't. Not with mockito anyway, and not with scalamock. Maybe you can find another library that can do it for you, but (1) it is out of topic here and (2) I bet, it'll take you more than 10 minutes.